# Creating a user profile to user auth django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm trying to create a profile for my user using django rest auth model, but when I'm sending the data to the user's creation, the user's image is not being filled, that is, it's getting null, I tried to send the node as much as image, as much as profile.image, but without success below my code follows:

[image]

**models\profile.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

**serializers\user.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from src.v1.user.models.profile import Profile
from .profile import ProfileSerializer


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )
    username = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, write_only=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_profile(user):
        """
        Get or create profile
        """

        profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return ProfileSerializer(profile, read_only=True).data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(email=validated_data['email'],
                    username=validated_data['username'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'profile')
```

***serializers\profile.py***

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from src.v1.user.models.profile import Profile


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'


class ProfileSerializerUpdate(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('image',)
```

**views\user.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from src.v1.user.serializers.user import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class UserView(APIView):
    """
    Creates the user.
    """

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                json = serializer.data
                json['token'] = token.key
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Do your images land on the server/root folder of your project? Can you take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SerializerMethodField` is read only by design. So it is not just the image, nothing is getting posted on the profile.

Also, creating the profile if it doesn't exist during a GET request is a bad design because generally, GET requests should be safe and not alter the state of the application.

You should instead, create the profile during user creation. Since there is just one field to be posted in the profile, it may be simpler and more effective to use a flat representation for the post data.

This is what you should do.

**serializers/user.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField(write_only=True)

    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    username = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(email=validated_data['email'], username=validated_data['username'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, image=validated_data['image')
        return user
```

Now you can post your image field with the rest of the user fields

Comment: @JeffersonBruchado you're welcome. I'm glad I could help